# Charset names: Are there any other commonly used "misspellings" of charsets such as "UTF8"?

Tags: character-encoding

My first question on SO :-)

**Background:** I'm working on software that needs to filter HTTP traffic. While working on the part that needs to check the content of POST requests, the question has come up for how to interpret the received data with respect to the charset.

In order to know which charset names my code should accept in the "Content-Type" header I first looked for an exhaustive list of charset names and found this: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets

(Of course that list is way too long to support them all and I will select a small subset that is relevant in my case.)

**Question:** From the list I take it that "UTF8" (without dash) is not a IANA-defined name of a charset, however it seems that it is still used sometimes anyway and most servers/browsers will understand it. Are there any more such cases of commonly understood charset names which are not listed by IANA that my filter should be able to understand?

Generally: Is there a "more complete" list somewhere?

More specifically: Are there any aliases for the US-ASCII charset that are not listed by IANA?

Answer (score 1):

Masato Kinugawa (@kinugawamasato) made lists of acceptable charset names for each web browser. See http://l0.cm/encodings/list/ .

For example, the charset names that treated as alias of US-ASCII in Chrome are:

- windows-1252
- ansi_x3.4-1968
- ascii
- cp1252
- cp819
- csisolatin1
- ibm819
- iso_8859-1
- iso_8859-1:1987
- iso88591
- iso8859-1
- ISO-8859-1
- iso-ir-100
- l1
- latin1
- us-ascii
- x-cp1252

As described in the site, you can also test the behavior of your browser by your self in http://l0.cm/encodings/check/ .